# Seeking other source of information for road networks to increase precision of shapefiles in Balkans

Tags: geospatial, open-access

I am trying to create an infrastructure map for Balkan countries. The thing is that for countries such as Albania, Bosnia - Herzegovina e.tc., the shapefiles from OpenStreetMap http://download.geofabrik.de, as well as from DIVA-GIS https://www.diva-gis.org/gdata. However, the road network is not precise. For instance, there are many "gaps" between the lines, looking like something is missing...

Is it possible to find another source of information for shapefiles of roads at a country level?